# How to fix DELETE method not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, eloquent

My delete method is not deleting from the database and I can't seem to see what it is I'm missing in my code when I click on delete. I've provide my blade file, controller and wweb.php file below, any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Blade File

```
<div class="row max-inner">
     @foreach ($tshirts as $tshirt)
           @auth
               <form action="{{ route('t-shirtsAdmin.destroy', $tshirt) }}" method="POST">
                   @csrf
                   @method('DELETE')
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">DELETE</button>
    
               </form>
           @endauth
                    
           <div class="columns col-6 collection-item">
               <div class="row">
                    <a href="#">
                          <div class="slider">
                              @foreach (json_decode($tshirt->filenames) as $picture)
                                  <div>
                                       <img src="{{ asset('files/' . $picture) }}" alt="kids top" loading="lazy">
                                  </div>
                              @endforeach
                          </div>
    
                          <div>
                          <div>
                               <div class="columns col"><i class="fas fa fa-child"></i> {{ $tshirt->gender }} top </div>
                               <div class="columns col"><i class="fas fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ $tshirt->age }} Years</div>
                               <div class="columns col"><i
                                                class="fas fa fa-tag"></i>
                                            Kshs 250</div>
    
                           </div>
                           <div class="row" style="display: flex; text-align: center; ">
                                <div class="columns col"><i class="fas fa fa-phone"></i> 0700 00000</div>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                  </a>
             </div>
         </div>
     @endforeach
</div>
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('t-shirtsAdmin', 'App\Http\Controllers\TshirtController');
```

CONTROLLER

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Models\Tshirt;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class TshirtController extends Controller
    {
       
        public function destroy(Tshirt $tshirt)
        {
    
            
            $tshirt->delete();
            return redirect(route('t-shirts'))->with('flash', 'T-shirt Deleted Successfully');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: In form action use `$tshirt->id` in argument of route function `{{ route('t-shirtsAdmin.destroy', $tshirt->id) }}`.

Comment: Nope, all works well but data doesn't get deleted!

Comment: use id to delete the record.

Comment: try to do dd($tshirt) in side destroy method , let us to show the result

Comment: Adding $tshirt->id did not work @MohamedAhmed it returns an empty array!

Comment: because your route parameter is  not `{tshirt}`, what is the output of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @sta 
DELETE    | t-shirtsAdmin/{t_shirtsAdmin}      | t-shirtsAdmin.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , this problem because model binding , you can solve this by 2 way first :-

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Tshirt::find($id)->delete();
    // or Tshirt::destroy($id);
    return redirect(route('t-shirts'))->with('flash', 'T-shirt Deleted Successfully');
}
```

second :- for route binding to work you should have type-hinted variable names match a route segment name, as the doc required : so your method will be like this :-

```
    public function destroy(Tshirt $t-shirtsAdmin)
    {
// $t-shirtsAdmin is the name of the router 
        $t-shirtsAdmin->delete();
        return redirect(route('t-shirts'))->with('flash', 'T-shirt Deleted Successfully');
    }
```

you can find the route name var , when you run
php artisan route:list , you will find the var like this : t-shirtsAdmin/{t-shirtsAdmin} so you should use it in controller to bind it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant just call the $tshirt param and expect it to delete, try something like this:

```
$id = $tshirt->id;
Tshirt::destroy($id);
return redirect(route('t-shirts'))->with('flash', 'T-shirt Deleted Successfully');
```

Comment: Oh I see, in your route list the param passed is {t_shirtsAdmin} so insted of $tshirt varible, try $id = $t_shirtsAdmin->id; And if that doesnt work try finding the t_shirtsAdmin with $tshirt = Tshirt::find(t_shirtsAdmin); Hope this helps for any future problems because I see that you have found an answer!